# onclick Iframe link - this link open in new tab / window

Tags: html, css, iframe

i have this iFrame -

`<iframe src="http://mp3yoyo.com/ads.php" scrolling="no" width="500" height="80" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

but when i click on link of any ads then it open in same window.

I want to open all links of iFrame in new window.

I have already try by adding `target="_blank"` and `<base target="_blank" />` but i am not opening link in new window so please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help:
http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=678138

In general, you should be telling the links to open in new windows (in the anchor tag).  You can control the action of the anchor tag in css, but I don't think iFrames support css like divs do (as iFrame isn't really part of CSS 3 to my knowledge).

If you use div instead of iFrame, according to CSS 3.0, you can give the div a class or an id and then control the anchor tag in the css, like so:

```
<div id="myDiv>
  <a href="whatever.html">stuff</a>
</div>
```

and then in your CSS file:

```
#myDiv a{
 target-name:new;
 target-new:tab;
}
```

I don't think this is actually supported yet, however; so this is largely theoretical.

Comment: I do not know what is link and where is <a tag because this link is generating from ads script. so i can not add target=_blank in a tag.

Comment: <div id="myDiv>
  <a href="whatever.html">stuff</a>
</div>

and then in your CSS file:

#myDiv a{
 target-name:new;
 target-new:tab;
} NOT WORKING

Comment: When i click on ADSSSSSS then its working fine. But when i click on links of ads then Do not Work. So alert not appear . HELP mE !

Comment: The CSS won't work because no browser supports this yet.  Complain to Mozilla/Google/Microsoft :)  Personally I don't think there is a solution, but feel free to look around.  The only way I know to make a new window/tab pop up is to include that instruction in the anchor tag.  Perhaps there's a javascript solution, that's not my forte.

Comment: So Joe there is NO Solution for it ! can any one your friend can help me ?